# PHP install package globally: apt-get vs composer

Tags: php, linux, symfony, composer-php, apt-get

I found there are two options to install PHP package globally in Linux (Ubuntu 16.04):

1. Using `composer`:

   ```
   composer global require symfony/finder
   ```

   The package will be located at `~/.config/composer/vendor/`

   [image]
2. Using `apt-get`:

   ```
   apt-get install php-symfony-finder
   ```

   The package will be located at `/usr/share/php/`

   [image]

   This directory `/usr/share/php/` is also in default PHPs `include_path` (I have PHP 7.2)

   [image]

---

There are several questions I have:

**Why would I want to install package globally ?**

I know it's useful to install php tools globally, like `phpunit` - It has binary file and it allows you to run tests everywhere, so you don't have to install it in every project.
But what about `symfony/finder` for example ? What is particular use of this package installed globally ?

**What is the difference between 1 and 2 option ?**

Does it have any different use cases or different effects ?

Comment: Too many questions in one go. BUT one thing about apt-get is that you have to take the version that is defined in the packages.  Usually they are a bit behind the latest versions - sometimes quite a bit.

Comment: I imagine that there are things that are not only used by php. In this case you'd do apt-get. (maybe i'll say something dumb but i was thinking about wkhtmltopdf)

Comment: The version installed with `apt-get` is global; it can be used by other users of the system. The one installed with `composer` is located in your home directory; only you can use it. If you are the only user of the computer then this doesn't make any difference. However, the version installed with `composer` is always the most recent version while the one installed by `apt-get` is updated less often and, at some point, it can be frozen and not updated any more.

Comment: Phpunit is a tool, as you said. symfony/finder is part of the project/dependency of the project, so you have to keep it per-project. Imagine developing one symfony4 project and maintaining one running on symfony 2.7. There are not same versions of finder, so you would have to keep 2 versions of your globally installed finder. Or you would have to keep different versions for dev branch and for master branch. Overkill

Comment: @Nigel Yeah too many, the question about windows doesn't actually matter to me. first and second questions I think a bit same. Anyway, all comments are good.

Comment: @Lilian This make sence

Comment: @axiac Thanks, didn't think about it. Im the only user of computer

Comment: Globally installing phpunit is a bad idea simply because it is a very active project with frequent changes needed to support the latest versions of php.  You will quickly run into the case when one app needs one version of phpunit while another app needs a different one.  I think the global installation capability is just a holdover from an earlier era.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why would I want to install package globally ?**

Normally, these are dependencies you want to use in *almost* every project, because they are available at a system level you can use them without duplicating their dependencies in every application you create.

For example, in my case I have `php_md`, `php_cs` for code formatting, `phpunit` for testing.

**What is the difference between 1 and 2 option ?**

Both are package managers, they make sure every package installed has the correct dependencies, so their core functionality is similar.

Now, they have several differences:

- Their focus in the packages they manage, `composer` is specific for `php` based packages but `apt-get` is for Linux and more system level oriented.
- Their package database, `composer` uses [packagist](https://packagist.org/) and `apt-get` uses a selection of repositories and ppas (you can find them in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`).
- The package selection, since `composer` is specialized in `php` you can expect a wider variety in anything `php` related.

In conclusion, you can clearly make it work with both, but I would recommend you to keep everything `php` related on composer, unifying them under the same manager.

Any other difference or correction I've overlooked is welcome.